# How to print floating point numbers in full precision

Tags: c#, floating-point, number-formatting, floating-accuracy

If I have a value of `0.3` which can not accuratly represented by `double` or `float` how can I print it's *real* value as string. A program like [this](https://tio.run/##NcuxCsIwFIXhuXmKS6cWtBTcLE6uCqUODuJwSWIJpAncGwtS8uwxLbqe83@S95JlSm82boTbh4OeOiEtMkNPfiScQCyi4IDBSJi9UXBF4yoOlMXjCUgj1yCKHBUzEljjNJzg7B17q5tBo7rkqaq7X6Dy@7IeQ9Mjsa5WsJ1/cicT9GbKpT0OsdyBWoMoYkptcxBf):

```
using System;
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        var d = float.Parse(line);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:R}", d);
    }
}
```

with `0.3` as input does print `0.3` which is odd to me since according to [this](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) it should be something like `0.300000011920928955078125`.

So the question is how can I force .net to format `float`/`double` as its *real* value.

Comment: "its real value." --> some large and small `double` take 100's digits to express [_exactly_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).  Usually 17 significant digits is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

> `R` recommended for the `BigInteger` type only. For `Double` types, use
>   "G17"; for `Single` types, use "G9".

So, try to use `G9` (because `float` gives you up to 9 significant digits of precision), it gives you an expected output

```cs
Console.WriteLine("{0:G9}", d);
```

At my end I'll see `0.300000012` value